# submit multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having multiple iframes in one page each one contains a form , and i put the submit button outside the iframes , and when user press on submit all forms should be submited and then the page should be closed , any one can help me in this?

this function called onclick on submit button

```
function Save_Close()
     {
        if (window.frames.intake_pat_info_iframe && window.frames.intake_pat_info_iframe._Submit('Update')) {
            window.frames.intake_pat_info_iframe._Submit('Update');

        }
        if (window.frames.intake_job_info_iframe && window.frames.intake_job_info_iframe._Submit('Update')) {
            window.frames.intake_job_info_iframe._Submit('Update');

        }
        if (window.frames.intake_spine_his_iframe && window.frames.intake_spine_his_iframe._Submit('Update')) {
            window.frames.intake_spine_his_iframe._Submit('Update');

        }
        if (window.frames.intake_past_med_history_iframe && window.frames.intake_past_med_history_iframe._Submit('Update')) {
            window.frames.intake_past_med_history_iframe._Submit('Update');
    }
```

....

```
<input type="button" id="" name="" value="Save & Close" onclick="Save_Close()"/>
```

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can use Javascript and your iframes are all being served from the same server, it's not that hard. A completely pure inline JS approach looks like (this is using ASP.NET for the server-side stuff but the important bit is the onclick() handler in the button)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>IFRAME form submit demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe name="iframe1" src="my_form.aspx"></iframe>
  <iframe name="iframe2" src="my_form.aspx"></iframe>
  <iframe name="iframe3" src="my_form.aspx"></iframe>
  <iframe name="iframe4" src="my_form.aspx"></iframe>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit All IFrames" 
           onclick="for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) { frames[i].document.forms[0].submitButton.click(); }" />
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: now explicitly calls form.submitButton.click() instead of form.submit() to invoke functions bound to submit button's Click handler.

Comment: i want to use the function inside these IFrames to submit the forms

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to achieve.

Each IFrame is a different document, and a submit button will only work on a single form, the one that is belongs to.

The get this to work, you will need to collect you data from all IFrames using javascript to populate one or more hidden fields on the form that the submit button is on.

If the different IFrames are on different domains however, this will not be possible due to the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) security policy.

Comment: I'm having function in each iframe can submit the included form there,the global button should call these functions to submit forms , but it submit only the first form..

Comment: @ama - That's right. A submit button will only submit the form it is on. If you want to call functions on other IFrames, you need to call them from your submit button through javascript. It is difficult to give you more specific advice without seeing your code.